# Wrong image show up in my ListView rows

Tags: android, listview

I use this code in my getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
    }
    Order o = items.get(position);

    if (o != null) {
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        ImageView thumb = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (o.getOrderDrawable() != null) {
            thumb.setImageDrawable(o.getOrderDrawable());
        } else {
            tt.setText(o.getOrderTitle());
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

The problem is when scrolling; sometimes the correct image shows, but sometimes when scrolling back/forward, the images shows randomly and that is not associated with the row.

The images are downloaded from the web.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Android's `ListView` reuses list items when they aren't need anymore. For this reason, you need to make sure all views that should change, will actually get changed.

Your problem is that if you don't find a drawable for the current list item, you don't empty nor hide the `ImageView`. You should do `thumb.setImageDrawable(null)` in that case, or `thumb.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! The problem was that some of my images was gone on the web server. Thank you for this.

Comment: when I want to display placeholder images while the images are grabbed from the internet. How would I do that? And which operation is the expensive one the vi.inflate(R.layout.listrow,null) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you stop using the convertView you get (which you absolutely should), and generate a whole new View to return every time, does it work right? I think the problem is in the way you reuse the views.

Comment: don't stop reusing views. You have to reuse the views correct but you definitely should reuse them.

Comment: What Janusz said. Try to build a list with a few dozen items, and fling through it (or worse, fast scroll through it). Without reusing views, performance will be horrible.

Answer (score -1):

I tried using the solution marked here as correct, but it doesn't solve the problem of wrong image during scrolling.
I tryied the second one (Zsombor Erdődy-Nagy) and now it's really ok. So thanks Zsombor :-)

Here it is my snippet:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list, null);
    }
    */
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list, null);
    final Status status = getItem(position);
    if (status != null) {
        TextView statusName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusName);
        TextView statusText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        TextView statusWhen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusWhen);
        TextView statusScreenName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusScreenName);
        final ImageView statusUserImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusUserImage);
        statusName.setText(status.getUser().getName());
        statusScreenName.setText("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName());
        statusText.setText(status.getText());
        statusWhen.setText(dateTimeFormatter.format(status.getCreatedAt()));
        URL url = status.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
        String imageCacheKey = url.getPath();
        Drawable cachedImage = imageCache.get(imageCacheKey);
        if (null != cachedImage) {
            statusUserImage.setImageDrawable(cachedImage);
        } else {
            new DownloadImageTask(statusUserImage, imageCacheKey).execute(url);
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, I was having the same experience as you but then I realized that I need to setVisibility(View.GONE) for EVERY view (all the TextViews and ImageViews). Once I did that, I was able to then reuse the convertView. I think it is better, probably more efficient to reuse when possible.

Comment: This is definitely not the way to go. Everytime a new list item needs to be shown, you're creating it entirely from scratch. Inflayout layouts is a very expensive operation. You should reuse the convertView. I'm sure it works, just not efficiently. If you reuse the convertView and you still have wrong images showing up, it's because you're not correctly setting all the views in your list item.